# is the software in Google's Chromecast devices open source?

Tags: open-source, licensing, chromecast

I have tried to find the answer but I don't see any place explaining what software is in the Chromecast and under what license is distributed. Is the software in Google's Chromecast devices open source?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about whether a specific tool is open source or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://code.google.com/p/chromecast-mirrored-source/ for the open source portions of the product.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the repository is still empty:    git clone https://code.google.com/p/chromecast-mirrored-source/    
Cloning into 'chromecast-mirrored-source'...    
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

Comment: Look at the other repositories - there are about 8 of them.

Comment: Thanks very much. I see there is a kernel and chromium repositories, which seems to indicate it's a Linux system with a Chrome front-end.